# MQ - view messages - text limit

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms, ibm-mq

While browsing the messages in MQ explorer, it only displays the first 1000 characters. We are not able to see the complete message. Is there any freeware available that can be used to view the complete message ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Before switching to something else, have you tried adjusting the WMQ Explorer settings?

First, get to the Preferences dialog:
[image]

Then select the Messages panel and adjust the value:
[image]

The reason that WMQ Explorer has these defaults set is to prevent an apparent "hang" if there were, for example, 3500 messages of size 64k.  Given these defaults, Explorer will download no more than 500 of them and only the first 10k bytes of each.  Given the defaults, Explorer can browse a deep queue with large messages and still return in a predictable amount of time.

The same issues hold true for any other browser tool since the bottleneck is the network and not the tool.

That said, if you want to look at other desktop client tools, [SupportPac MO71](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMO71) is quite popular.

Comment: Glad to help!  Please do also explore the options in the other answers.  Although Explorer is the "official" tool, it is good to have some familiarity with the others and, who know, you may like them even better after trying them.  If you ever want an index of tools, check out http://capitalware.biz (Roger from the other answer).  He keeps an extensive list of all known 3rd party WMQ tools and products, in addition to his own.

Comment: Thanks from 2017! :)

Answer (score 2):

Hermes jms uses the jms api - so you will not get all wmq features, but many. Its open source.
[Hermes JMS latest download](http://hermesjms.com/patches)

I also like mqmon [MO71](http://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24000142) and rfhutil [IH03](http://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24000637), free from IBM, but they are native WMQ and have their pros and cons.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at [MQ Visual Edit](http://www.capitalware.biz/mqve_overview.html). It is a stand-alone MQ message editing tool but it is not free.